# FIFINE microphone USB can not install in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, microphone

I can't install and/or configure FIFINE microphone (usb microphone) in the following operating system:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"  
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"  
ID=ubuntu  
ID_LIKE=debian  
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"  
VERSION_ID="20.04"  
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"  
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"  
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"  
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"  
VERSION_CODENAME=focal  
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

I run `lsusb` and get the following result:

```
$ lsusb  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:d102 Alcor Micro Corp. HD WebCam  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp.   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/dvdrw"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.